# Why no answer when trying to sum even Fibonacci numbers

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, fibonacci

I defined a function to calculate fibonacci numbers which works well.

Now I'm trying to add up all the even numbered fibonacci numbers <= n than are also <= 4000000 but I'm getting no output.

```
def fib_iterative(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    for i in range(0, n):
        a, b = b, a + b
    return a

def sum_even_fibs(n):
    total = 0
    n = 0
    while fib_iterative(n) < 4000000:
        if fib_iterative(n) % 2 == 0:
            total += fib_iterative(n)
            n += 1
    return total

print(sum_even_fibs(10))
# 1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55. 
# 2 + 8 + 34 = 44
```

Comment: Remark: odd+odd=even and even+odd=odd, hence even fibonacci numbers are for n%3 == 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because you are not doing it until `n`, you are doing it until `4000000`.

You can combine both of your functions to create this.

```
def sum_even_fibs(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    t = 0
    for i in range(n):
        a, b = b, a + b
        if a % 2 == 0:
            t += a
    return t

print(sum_even_fibs(10)) #44
```

as someone in the comments pointed out, every third number is even so you can compress this down to

```
def sum_even_fibs(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    t = 0
    for i in range(n // 3):
        a, b = a + 2 * b, 2 * a + 3 * b
        t += a
    return t

print(sum_even_fibs(10)) #44
```

for the specific case where you don't want to do any numbers above 4000000, you can add this if statement

```
def sum_even_fibs(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    t = 0
    for i in range(n // 3):
        a, b = a + 2 * b, 2 * a + 3 * b
        if a >= 4000000:
            print("the fibonacci numbers in this calculation exceed 4000000")
            return None
        t += a
    return t
```

Comment: Thanks! This works great but I can't figure out how to only return answers for cases when a <= 4000000   Any clues?

Comment: @newc00der what would you like the function to return if n is more than 4000000? nothing?

Comment: A message stating "the fibonacci numbers in this calculation exceed 4000000"

Answer (score 2):

With regard to the code:

```
if fib_iterative(n) % 2 == 0:
    total += fib_iterative(n)
    n += 1
```

This will only increment `n` if the `n`th Fibonacci number is even. That means that, as soon as you reach `1`, it becomes an infinite loop. If you put a `print(n)` immediately between the `while` and `if` statements, you'll see this - it will print out `0` followed by a rather large number of `1`s (presumably until you get bored and stop it forcefully).

To fix it, you need to bring the `n += 1` back one indent level so that it's incremented regardless:

```
if fib_iterative(n) % 2 == 0:
    total += fib_iterative(n)
n += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you were just doing this up to `n=5`.  You should be calculating five fibonacci numbers.  Instead, you're calculating all of the fibonacci numbers up to the current one three times!  For each `n`, you should call `fib_iterative` exactly once and reuse the result.  You're also discarding the value of your `n` parameter.

```
def sum_even_fibs(n):
    total = 0
    for x in range(n):
        current = fib_iterative(x)
        if current > 4000000:
            break
        if not current % 2:
            total += current
    return total
```

This is still inefficient, because you're recalculating `n-1` values of every time you call `fib_iterative(n)`.  Instead, a generator based solution will allow you to calculate each value only once.

```
from itertools import takewhile

def fib(n):
    x = 0
    y = 1
    for _ in range(n):
        yield x
        x, y = y, x+y

def sum_even_fibs(n):
    fibs = fib(n)
    evens = (x for x in fibs if not x%2)
    less_than_4000000 = takewhile(lambda x: x < 4000000, evens)
    return sum(less_than_4000000)
```

Comment: Thanks! A few things I've never seen ('itertools', 'takewhile', yield', 'lambda'). I'll try to get my head around them...